# Дана последовательность из 100 целых чисел

Tags: c++

1) Дана последовательность из 100 целых чисел. Определить количество чисел в наиболее длинной подпоследовательности из подряд идущих нулей.

```
#include "clocale"
#include "time.h"
#include "iostream"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    const int n = 100;
    int mas[n];
    srand(time(NULL));
    int posl = 0;
    int maxposl = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
    {
        mas[i] = rand() % 3;
        int j = i;
        while (mas[j] == 0)
        {
            posl++;
            j++;
        }
        if (posl > maxposl) maxposl = posl;
        posl = 0;
        i = j;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
        cout << mas[i] << " ";
    cout << "\r\n";
    cout << "Максимальная последовательность 0 : " << maxposl;
    cout << "\r\n";
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

**Обновление**

```
0 0 6619251 1 2 0 3211309 1 1 2 1 1 0 5860720 2 0 1999597368 2 0 5832704 2 2 0 1  
999430465 1 1 2 0 4454684 1 0 1999700908 2 0 5832704 2 1 0 0 128 0 4454624 2 2 0  
 -781389377 0 1999700908 0 1999021708 0 -1 1 1 0 0 5 2 0 4454744 2 0 4454808 2 2  
 2 2 2 1 2 2 1 0 36 1 1 2 0 1496039077 2 2 2 0 17445136 1 1 1 2 0 68 0 17440747  
0 -2 0 17439600 0 4454912 2 1
```

> Максимальная последовательность 0 : 2
> Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .

Неправильно его задает, не должен он такие числа выводить.

Comment: неправильно выводит массив

Comment: Вывод массива правильный, ошибка где-то раньше.

Вы не пробовали воспользоваться отладчиком?

Comment: Что надо сделать, чтобы убрать такие числа 3211309, 6619251?

Comment: У вас неверное решение задачи, закомментируйте полностью ваш цикл while, и у вас все станет на места. Вы за предел массива выходите.

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение, если я правильно понял вопрос вашего задания. Разбирайтесь.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <time.h>
#include <set>

using namespace std;

int main () {    
    vector<int> v;
    set<int> s;

    int tmp;

    srand(time(0));
    // заполнили числами
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        v.push_back(tmp = rand() % 3);
        cout << tmp;
    }
    // ищем максимальную последовательность
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        if (v[i] == 0){
            tmp++;
        } else {
            // cout << "[" << tmp << "]" << endl; // отладка
            s.insert(tmp);
            tmp = 0;
        }
    }

    set<int>::iterator it = s.end(); it--;
    cout << endl << "max count equal: " << *it << endl;
}
```